# Python. How do i count the number of divisors in nested for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I have a code that generates triangular numbers, calculates the divisors for each triangular number and prints out 3 columns where the first column is the input numbers, the second column is the triangular numbers and the third column is the divisors of each triangular number. How can I count the number of divisors of each triangular number(count the numbers in the third column)?

```
for num in range(10):
    triangle_number = num*(num+1)//2
    print(num, end = '   ')
    print(triangle_number, end = '     ')
    for divisor in range(1, triangle_number+1):
        if triangle_number%divisor == 0:
            print(divisor,  end = ',')
    print()
```

Output looks like this:

```
0   0     
1   1     1,
2   3     1,3,
3   6     1,2,3,6,
4   10     1,2,5,10,
5   15     1,3,5,15,
6   21     1,3,7,21,
7   28     1,2,4,7,14,28,
8   36     1,2,3,4,6,9,12,18,36,
9   45     1,3,5,9,15,45,
```

Comment: @ Tom Karzes fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a variable inside `for` loop and increment it when you get the divisor and print a the end.

```
for num in range(10):
    count = 0
    triangle_number = num*(num+1)//2
    print(num, end = '\t')
    print(triangle_number, end = '\t')
    for divisor in range(1, triangle_number+1):
        if triangle_number%divisor == 0:
            print(divisor,  end = ',')
            count += 1

    print("\t", count)
##Output:
##0   0          0
##1   1     1,   1
##2   3     1,3,     2
##3   6     1,2,3,6,     4
##4   10     1,2,5,10,   4
##5   15     1,3,5,15,   4
##6   21     1,3,7,21,   4
##7   28     1,2,4,7,14,28,  6
##8   36     1,2,3,4,6,9,12,18,36,   9
##9   45     1,3,5,9,15,45,  6
##Output order : input number, count of divisors divisors, triangular number
```

or you can create a list of divisors and measure length before printing.

```
for num in range(10):
    divisors = []
    triangle_number = num*(num+1)//2
    print(num, end = '\t')
    print(triangle_number, end = '\t')
    for divisor in range(1, triangle_number+1):
        if triangle_number%divisor == 0:
            divisors.append(divisor)

    print(len(divisors), "\t", ",".join(str(div )for div in divisors))
##Output:
##0 0   0    
##1 1   1    1
##2 3   2    1,3
##3 6   4    1,2,3,6
##4 10  4    1,2,5,10
##5 15  4    1,3,5,15
##6 21  4    1,3,7,21
##7 28  6    1,2,4,7,14,28
##8 36  9    1,2,3,4,6,9,12,18,36
##9 45  6    1,3,5,9,15,45
##Output order : input number, triangular number, count of divisors divisors
```

Answer (score 0):

You might replace your inner for loop using list comprehension and then just get length of that list using `len` function, that is replace:

```
for divisor in range(1, triangle_number+1):
    if triangle_number%divisor == 0:
        print(divisor,  end = ',')
```

with:

```
divisors = [divisor for divisor in range(1, triangle_number+1) if triangle_number%divisor == 0]
print(*divisors, sep=',', end='   ')
print(len(divisors), end='')
```

list comprehension is succint way of creating list which might be created via `append`ing inside `for loop`, `*` (star operator) does unpacking, if you would have list `x = [1, 2, 3]` then `print(*x)` is equivalent of `print(1, 2, 3)` and so on.